# Pull data from HTTP request API to Google Cloud

Tags: api, google-app-engine, google-bigquery, cloud, google-cloud-storage

I have an app that sending me data from an API. The data is semi-structured (json data)

I would like to send this data to Google Big Query in order to stock all the information.

However, I'm not able to find how can I do it properly.

So far I have used Node JS on my own server to get the data using POST request.

Could you please help me ? Thnak.

Comment: Lookup NodeJS library that does streaming insert.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bigquery API to do streaming inserts.

You can also write the data to PubSub or Google Cloud Storage and use dataflow pipelines to load them into bigquery (you can either use streaming inserts (incur costs) or batch load jobs (free))

You can also log in stackdriver and from there you can select and send to bigquery (there already exists direct options for it in GCP, note that under the hood it performs streaming inserts)

If you feel that setting up dataflow is complicated, you can store your files and perform batch load jobs by directly calling bigquery API. Note that there are limits on number of batch loads you can make in a day over a particular table (1000 per day)

Answer (score 0):

There is a page in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data) that lists all the possibilities of loading data to BigQuery.

For the simplicity, you can just send data from your local data soruce. You should use the Google Cloud client libraries for Big Query. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local) you have a guide on how to do that as well as a relevant code example.

But my honest recommendation is to [send data to Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/using-cloud-storage) and from there, to [load it to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage). This way the whole process will be more stable.

You can check all the options from the first link that I've posted and choose what you think that will fit best with your workflow.

Keep in mind the [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data#limitations) of this process.