# Pulling data from an API for Google DataFlow (Python) to ingest and to load onto BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I am new to data ingestion but have worked through some examples of using Google Data Flow in batch and stream mode. I am now ready to build the actual project. However, I need to choose one of multiple architectures to achieve my goal.

## Goal:

To call an API as to extract data. The data needs to be processed and loaded onto a Big Query table.

## Details:

Here we go into the finer details:

### API:

It is the [Easylog Cloud](https://www.easylogcloud.com/) API. I can successfully make calls from it using the requests library in Python. The API has multiple locations with multiple devices. Each device samples a reading every 60 seconds. The number of devices may increase with time. Assume that I am able to filter only readings that have not been seen from every call to the API. I will most likely be making a call to the API every 2 minutes (the team still needs to decide).

### Transformations

My function that calls the API already does most of the data processing and transformations. So I do not actually have the need to do any transforms in say an Apache Beam pipeline.

### Data Sink

The data needs to be read into a Big Query table. This can either be streamed or batch. I assume a batch insert is cheaper. The answer by Pravin Dhinwa on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58398116/pull-data-from-http-request-api-to-google-cloud) suggests a batch insert to be free.

## Possible solutions

Here I discuss some possible solutions. Keep in mind that they might be rubbish. The goal of this question is to identify whether one of these are good and to suggest a better one.

### Solution 1:

I could use Google Cloud Functions to pull from the API and directly write/insert to the Big Query table. This would be a periodically scheduled function using Cloud Scheduler. I might write some temporary data into Cloud Storage buckets from this script as well. This approach seems simple. However, due  to the simplicity, I question its robustness and potential to be costly.

### Solution 2:

I can deploy a Google Cloud Data Flow pipeline using Apache Beam. The pipeline will have a ParDo function which pulls from the API. The pipeline then inserts into the Big Query table and writes some temporary data to Google Cloud Storage buckets. The pipeline is triggered by periodic Pub/Sub messages. These Pub/Sub messages need to be published by a scheduled job on Cloud Scheduler. I feel like this approach maintains a running pipeline such that it does not need to be set up periodically.

### Solution 3:

This is almost identical to solution 2. However, I do not pull from the API using a ParDo function in the pipeline. Instead I schedule a Cloud Function to deploy periodically using Cloud Scheduler. This function pulls from the API and sends the results to a Pub/Sub topic. These messages trigger the pipeline which writes to the Big Query table and buckets. This approach seems like an overkill version of solution 1 though by adding an intermediate pipeline whereas solution 1 does everything in the cloud function.

## Requirements:

I am looking for a solution which fulfills the following requirements with descending priority importance:

1. Robustness: it must not fail and must last a long time.
2. Low cost: I feel that doing batch writes and batch ingestion is cheaper
3. Simplicity: as I am a beginner, a simple approach would be easier for me to debug or fix when things go wrong.

Comment: does your workflow have heavy data processing and transformations steps? How much data will be consumed with each API request?

Comment: The device has multiple sensors that sensor every 60 seconds. I then batch load all such readings every hour. The transformations are are not heavy. The workload/amount of data will likely become more in the future as additional sensors are added.

Comment: hey @Dylan, I have provided an answer. Let me know if it was helpful

Comment: Your answer was helpful. I appreciate it. I also appreciate the robustness that DataFlow provides. I ended up testing both solutions. With DataFlow the pull from the API could be written in a different way as to lessen the work done by that function. In other words, the API pull for the cloud function pulled the entire batch of data for all sensors whereas the API pull for DataFlow could dump data for each sensor as it pulled from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend Solution 2 since Dataflow is robust for your streaming pipeline. You do not need to maintain it once it works.

Answer (score 1):

A bit more description to @XQHu answer, Dataflow is a managed service which is capable of executing variety of data transformation and heavy data processing. 
If the data processing and transformation steps aren't complex and heavy and doesn't require much computation the simple answer would align to what you've mention in solution 1. ie using Google Cloud Function. 
However, since you mentioned in the comments that with time, the data workload will tend to increase and to build more robust batch production pipeline, which would be less prone to errors, it is recommended to go with Dataflow.